# Parse server atomic increment result

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

In my Parse backend I have an array that contains unique number codes, so users must not be able to get the same code twice. For that reason somewhere in a column of some table I am keeping an index to this array.

Now there is a very simple operation - users ask for a unique code. The cloud function increments the current value of the index and returns the value of the array at the new index. The problem is that at first glance the Parse JS API has only increment operation performed atomically, but not the following read operation, since increment doesn't return a promise with a value which was set during **THAT** increment.

Now imagine the following scenario (pseudocode):

Field `index` has value `76`, two users try to get the next code at the same time:

User1 -> `increment('index') -> save -> then(obj1) -> return array[obj1.index]`

User2 -> `increment('index') -> save -> then(obj2) -> return array[obj2.index]`

Now atomic increment will guarantee that after these 2 calls the index column will have value `78`. But what about `obj1` and `obj2`? If their value reading was not done atomically together with the increment operation, but was done through fetching after the increment was performed, then they both might have value `78`! And the whole uniqueness logic will be broken.

Is there a way to get the atomic write operation result in Parse?

Comment: try review on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: thanks, but I need something more human readable and memorable, in my case those are 4 digit numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment does return the final value that was atomically incremented:

1. First the unit test to show how it is used:

   ```
   fit('increment', (done) => {
       new Parse.Object('Counter')
         .set('value', 1)
         .save()
         .then(result => {
           console.log('just saved', JSON.stringify(result));
           return result
             .increment('value')
             .save();
         })
         .then(result => {
           console.log('incremented', JSON.stringify(result))
           expect(result.get('value')).toBe(2);
           done();
         })
         .catch(done.fail);
     });
   ```
2. Behind the scenes, here's what's happening (if you're using mongo, there's similar for postgress too):

   - [MongoAdapter](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/193e5a42787a80d47aeffcaa7852ff006be21df5/src/Adapters/Storage/Mongo/MongoTransform.js#L663)
     turns into a mongo $inc operation which is returned
   - [Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) documentation explaining $inc which includes "$inc is an atomic operation within a single document."

Comment: To be 100% clear: does the `increment()` update and return the final value, or the `save()` ? i.e. is it possible that if there was a delay between the `increment` call and the `save` call would it be possible for an external change to effect the result ?

Comment: Or does `increment` _mark_ the object for _incrementation_  which is then executed during the `save` call?

Comment: Also what would happen if two or more fields in the same record are both marked for incrementation prior to the save call ?

Comment: 1. `increment()` doesn't do the update, it just marks the field for increment when `save` is executed.  2. You can mark as many fields as you want for `increment` it'll work just as you'd expect.  But don't take my word for it, give it a try ;).